# SQL Server: how can I get unique row after joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not seeking for `Distinct` solution. I think that doesn't work for my situation.

I have 3 tables, as below:

Table1

```
AccountNo, Date, Property, Ascores, Bscores
```

Table2

```
AccountNo, Date, Property, Cscores
```

Table3

```
AccountNo, Date, Property, Dscores, Escores
```

I want to join them all together. `AccountNo, Date, Property` should be duplicated but `Ascores, Bscores, Cscores, Dscores` & `Escores` should be summed up by `AccountNo, Date, Property`.

I found many resources online, it seems correlated subquery may a the solution but I have not idea how to write.

Could anyone help me, Thank you

I tried this SQL code:

```
SELECT
    T1.AccountNo,
    T1.[Date],
    T1.Property,
    SUM(T1.Ascores),
    SUM(T1.Bscores),
    SUM(T2.Cscores),
    SUM(T3.Dscores),
    SUM(T3.Escores)
FROM
    Table1 T1 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Table2 T2 ON T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo
FULL OUTER JOIN
    Table3 T3 ON T1.AccountNo = T3.AccountNo
GROUP BY
    T1.AccountNo, T1.[Date], T1.Property
```

However the output is something like this:

[image]

That is totally not the result I want ....

The ideal output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Please share some test data for us to test the issue

Comment: Maybe the date contains a time part causing the account no, the date and the property to repeat themselves?

Comment: @TheGameiswar , sorry, that is company data, I cannot reveal it, I just can show the concept of my dilemma

Comment: your expected result does not make any sense. when you group by on AccountNo, Date and Property, you will get unique rows for those columns.

Comment: You can add some dummy data, with out test data ,any one can only guess

Comment: @ Ole EH Dufour, I am afraid not, I check it [Date] is actually Date and it is only 10 digits

Comment: @ FLICKER , Great, If it doesn't make sense. how? show me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: I agree with @Flicker that the expected result should have unique rows for those columns. So I take it that you want something else than just group by those columns

Comment: All I want is: each account with each day with each property, they all receive A,B,C,D,E scores. However , those 5 scores separated in 3 tables. Therefore, the concept is clear: account 1001, in 2018-03-10, in Area 51, has 5 different scores, only. the next row should not 1001+2018-03-10+Area 51

Comment: Aggegate each table individually before the join using Common Table Expressions or Derived Tables.

Comment: @dnoeth, Hi, I aggregated all 3 tables already, there are no data duplication. I only know the join table, could you please show me how to use CTE or Derived Tables?

Comment: In Excel, That is just vlookup question. Table1 is the primary table, AccountNo+Date+Property is the key, for Table2 and Table3 vlookup. Initially I thought join table can finish, but it doesn't..

Comment: No way that query has repeated T1.AccountNo, T1.[Date], T1.Property.  Even your desired result has repeats.  Learn to write a credible question.  VTC

Comment: You only join on `AccountNo`, but not on `[Date]` & `Property`, which will result in too many rows before the aggregation. And if you actually need the Full Joins you should use `coalesce(T1.AccountNo,T2.AccountNo,T3.AccountNo)` instead of `T1.AccountNo` and the joins must include `coalesce`, too. Overall Gordon's approach is probably the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `union all`:

```
select AccountNo, [Date], Property,
       sum(Ascores) as Ascores, 
       sum(Bscores) as Bscores, 
       sum(Cscores) as Cscores, 
       sum(Dscores) as Dscores, 
       sum(Escores) as Escores
from ((select t1.AccountNo, t1.[Date], t1.Property, t1.Ascores, T1.Bscores,
              0 as Cscores, 0 as Dscores, 0 as Escores
       from table1 t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.AccountNo, t2.[Date], t2.Property, 0 as Ascores, 0 as Bscores,
              t2.Cscores, 0 as Dscores, 0 as Escores
       from table2 t2
      ) union all      
      (select t3.AccountNo, t3.[Date], t3.Property, 0 as Ascores, 0 as Bscores,
              0 as Cscores, t3.Dscores, t3.Escores
       from table3 t3
      ) union all
     ) t
group by AccountNo, [Date], Property;
```

If your `date` is indeed declared as a *date* and not another type, this it does not explain the discrepancy you are seeing.  If it is any other type, then use `cast([Date] as date)` in the `select` and `group by`.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I got error msg: 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'HongKong' to data type int.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @YungLinMa . .. It would seem that you have a type mismatch.  It is unclear where the problem lies.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I found that Chinese characters occurring the errors. convert them or cast them into nvarchar is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems your date includes time also. Convert your date into a string to remove the time part and include only yyyy/mm/dd part. Now group based on this, then you will get distinct record for each day.